# Documentation of allowed HTML formatting for the Lightning Knowledge Rich Text Editor?

Tags: richtextarea, lightning-knowledge

Is there any documentation available of exactly what HTML is allowed in the Lightning Knowledge Rich Text Editor?

- [Rich Text Fields in Knowledge Articles](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.knowledge_rich_text_considerations.htm&type=5) (SF Help) states "When you paste content from a web page or another source into the editor, or if you edit the source HTML directly, unsupported tags are removed when you save the article. You don't receive a warning when code is removed."  However, there is no list of acceptable/not acceptable content.
- [Rich Text Editor](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_using_html_editor.htm&type=5) (SF Help) provides a list of supported tags for most use cases (those which do not use CKEditor), but later notes that Lightning Knowledge uses CKEditor (version 4.18.0 as of W'23), and does not list all supported content for that editor.
- [Editing Rich Text Area Fields in Records](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_using_rich_text_area.htm&type=5) (SF Help) covers all the editors, and includes a "support in Lightning Experience and the Salesforce mobile app" table, but that again does not include the CKEditor used in Lightning Content.
- [Rich Text Area Field Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_rich_text_area_limitations.htm&type=5) (SF Help) does not appear to address the Lightning Knowledge editor.

In addition to basic "remove some unsupported tags" behavior, we have also observed more subjective edits, such as removal of `<br>` tags immediately before the end of a block (such as an `<li>`).  It would be useful to have some documentation of the rules of the editor.

**Background/Additional Context**

We are helping a client transition their support website from another platform to an Experience Builder site.  This includes importing nearly 3000 HTML documents exported from their old system into SF Knowledge.  This has actually worked pretty well, but now the client's content team is reviewing the imported documents and finding/fixing issues.  For issues that affect a large number of articles (such as the `<br>`/`<li>` issue above), we are running a script to clean up the HTML prior to import, to reduce the amount of manual work involved, however, human editors are still working through the articles as well.  Coming from another (more flexible, with respect to HTML/CSS/JS content), they are asking for guidance on what works and what does not.  The lack of official documentation is an impediment.

Also, while I am aware that the WYSIWYG mode of the Rich Text editor is the intended primary UI, the "Source" (HTML Edit Mode) button does exist, and the content team are well acquainted with their existing HTML content; they will continue to need some direct HTML support.